# Trying to make Yes/No javascript popup but is not working

Tags: javascript, php

hello i am trying to make popup Yes/No in js but is not working, this is my code:

one version is this:

```
if($admin==1) 
    print('<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$value. '"> <BUTTON class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="AlertPopUp()" ><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #000000;"></i>  </BUTTON></a>');

function AlertPopUp(){
    let AlertPopUp = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this client?");
    if(AlertPopUp){
        window.open('delete.php?id='+$value);
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

This is working but if i press cancel still deletes the value so i tried making the window.open but the url gets the value from php $value so i dont know how to pass it.

The other method i tried is this:

```
if($admin==1) 
    print('<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$value. '" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this client?');"> <BUTTON class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="AlertPopUp()" ><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #000000;"></i>  </BUTTON></a>');
```

but this isnt working at all no popup appearing and the text isnt correct with '  ' so i tried " " but still nothing.

Comment: `<button>` inside `<a>` is invalid.

Comment: Start by writing valid HTML. Buttons aren't allowed inside links.

Comment: This code works without javascript it existed before, so how should i format it to still work as before but with the popup?

Comment: Use _either_ a button _or_ a link. When using a link, make sure you **prevent** its **default** behaviour

Comment: how do i get the $value of php to .value of javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($admin==1) 
    print('<td><BUTTON class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="AlertPopUp('.$value.')" ><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: #000000;"></i>  </BUTTON>');

function AlertPopUp(value){
    let AlertPopUp = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this client?");
    if(AlertPopUp){
        window.location.href='delete.php?id=' + value;
    }else{
        return;
    }
```

You pass the php value as parameter and then fetch it from the function.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you are working inside a PHP page, so it would be like this:
first of all remove the `<a> </a>` and leave only the button because otherwise the link found in href will be opened.

```
<? php $ admin = 1;  if ($ admin == 1) print ('<BUTTON class = "btn btn-outline-info" onclick = "AlertPopUp ()"> <i class = "fa-trash" style = "color: # 000000;" > </i> </BUTTON> '); ?>
```

// then we harp the JS script

```
<script>
function AlertPopUp(){
    let AlertPopUp = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this client?");
    if(AlertPopUp){
        window.open('delete.php?id=<?= $value ?>');
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: your method looks correct but the $value on js comes 0 any idea how to fetch it?

Comment: Just a little idea to understand the problem first you have to see if $ admin arrives with the value 1 so I would say to do before the IF do print ($ value); so if the value is one then on the revenue we put in JS you can change 'delete.php? id = <? php echo $ value; ?> 'otherwise you have to see why $ admin with the value 1 does not arrive so you have to check your php file

Comment: yes i check if admin is one and then the button shows its an image button that if you click deletes value of $value id